# Sweep with a broom or sweep my eyes across?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

In the song Viva La Vida by Coldplay, it says:

> I used to rule the world
>   Seas would rise when I gave the word
>   Now in the morning I sleep alone
>   **Sweep** the streets I used to own

How can I determine if the sweep there means "sweep the streets with a broom" or "sweep my eyes across the streets"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know it's not talking about sweeping eyes across the street because it doesn't mention eyes at all*.

So instead, we fall back to the normal meaning of "sweep".

<sub>**To be fair, there are probably at least a few song lyrics that would confuse this a lot by making use of unusual constructions and indirect allusions. This isn't one of them; there's nothing particularly strange going on here, grammatically or metaphorically.*</sub>